# Messed up this mid-term question

Tags: probability, statistics, elementary-set-theory

Let A and B be two events defined on a sample space S. If the probability that at least
one of them occurs is 0.3 and the probability that A occurs but B does not occur is 0.1, what is P(B)?
Hint: A = (A&B) or (A&B'), where B' is the complement of B.

I just cannot believe that I messed up this mid-term question. By at least I think it meant P(AUB) and P(A occurs but not B) probably meant P(A&B'). Then I couldn't solve anything and wrote down P(B)=0.5. So disappointed to not understand this type of concept yet.

Comment: Hint: Instead of the hint they have, consider that $A\cap B^c$ and $B$ are _disjoint_ events whose union is $A\cup B$.  Draw a Venn diagram if this puzzles you. In fact, it is a good idea to draw a Venn diagram anyway in solving problems such as these. Thus, $$P(A\cup B) = P(A\cap B^c) + P(B)$$ via the third axiom of probability. Can you take it from here?

Comment: @ Dilip. Yes, I think I can take it on from here. Thanks.

Comment: OK, so please write up a complete solution and post it as an answer to your own question so that this does not remain as an unanswered question. After a while you can even _Accept_ your answer as the one that is most satisfactory. Both practices are encouraged on this forum.

Comment: @Dilip Okay, I'll do that next time as the question is already answered. As I am new to this forum it can be a bit difficult to know the rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P(B) = 0.2

If you draw a simple venn diagram it may help you visualize it easier.

The fact that P(A U B) = 0.3 and that P(A∩B') = 0.1 is all you needed to determine P(B).

P(B) = P(A U B) - P(A∩B')

Comment: Yes, it's way easier to solve the problem by drawing a Venn diagram. The hint was the thing that confused me.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latexhelp/notation).